# Firefox keeps going unresponsive and crashing

Tags: firefox, security

Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit up to date.

I was recently hacked. Had to clean install from a live usb made off my network and network computers. Since clean installing firefox keeps going unresponsive and crashing.
It's the same with the open source and proprietary video drivers.

Firefox add-ons:

No-script, adblock plus, https everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely re-install Firefox.

```
Sudo apt-get remove firefox

Sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the settings in Firefox, hopefully you can complete the steps before it becomes unresponsive. To do so, go to the new config menu, open the Help menu, and then Troubleshooting Information. Click Reset Firefox.

Firefox will reset all your data (including addons, themes and profile data), and your Firefox installation will be like a brand new one (without the hassles of uninstalling and reinstalling the product, which anyway will continue to use the old settings and profile information). If everything works fine, then you can re-install your favorite addons.

Otherwise, you could try deleting (or backing up) your profiles directory, which is housed in $HOME/.mozilla/firefox.